# Reactjs - Need to bind a onClick handler twice?

Tags: reactjs

Coming from Vue.js (two way data flow) I have question about react one way data flow - I have a Parent that have a handler for its child onClick:

```
<div className="recipe-container">
                <button onClick={this.toggleRecipeList.bind(this)}>Show Recipes</button>
                <RecipeList showRecipe={this.showRecipe} list={this.state.recipes} />
            </div>
```

So, I pass `showRecipe` handler, which has only one parameter (and simply just logs it to the console).

My `RecipeList` looks like this (stateless func):

```
return (<ul className='recipe-list-bottom'>
        {
            props.list.map((rec, key) => {
                return <li onClick={props.showRecipe(rec)} key={key}>{rec.title}</li>
            })
        }

    </ul>)
```

I tried to launch `showRecipe(rec)` to have the current `rec` object as argument. Although I recive what I want, the handler is being fired from a `button` which is a sibling of `RecipeList`.

I manage to get it working by adding `onClick={props.showRecipe.bind(null,rec)}` to `li` element, but I find it really dirty way to do so.

Am I missing something? I thought `showRecipe(rec)` would be enough to get what I wanted. Why `showRecipe(rec)` is being fired with `this` set to `button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your second snippet has a classic error:

```
return (<ul className='recipe-list-bottom'>
        {
            props.list.map((rec, key) => {
                return <li onClick={props.showRecipe(rec)/*here*/} key={key}>{rec.title}</li>
            })
        }

    </ul>)
```

You are assigning the result of calling showRecipe to the onClick parameter, not the function itself. The `bind` solutions works, but if you want to pass the parameter rec without using `bind` you need to wrap the call:

```
return (<ul className='recipe-list-bottom'>
        {
            props.list.map((rec, key) => {
                return <li onClick={()=>props.showRecipe(rec)} key={key}>{rec.title}</li>
            })
        }

    </ul>)
```

Comment: Yeah, it does work! Silly me, idk why I thought it will be fired with that parameter :D. Thanks! Beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use es2015 stage-0 syntax in order to write it like this:

```
class Blah extends Component {
  onClick = (recipe) => e => this.props.showRecipe(recipe);

  render() { 
    return (
      <ul className='recipe-list-bottom'>
        {
            props.list.map((rec, key) => {
                return <li onClick={onClick(rec)} key={key}>{rec.title}</li>
            })
        }

      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```